# how to block the events of the parent when a child element is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

for example, when I click the button is also launched the event of the grid. How can I avoid it?

```
<Grid Tap="Grid_Tap">
    <Button Click="btn_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set  e.Handled=true; in the handler of button

```
void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Handler code here
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

[Handled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)